# How to pass Spring profile to Spring Boot application run by Jenkins Job?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jenkins

I need to run a Spring Boot app using different configuration files. In local I can do it with the following JVM Option:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=e1
```

What's the way to do this when I run the app from a Jenkins job?

Comment: You can also provide the same command in Jenkins with .jenkins file.

Comment: @sambit how do I do that?

Comment: You can provide complete command like java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=e1 yourapplication.jar. e1 is considered as your profile name

Comment: If you post an example for my question, I'll give you the points

Comment: You can also set the environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`.

Comment: @chrylis how do I set it from the Jenkins job?

Comment: I have provided the link which provides step by step and you can learn and help others also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that user knows .jenkins file, I provide below the code snippet.

```
node {

.... Other code 

stage("development") {
                withEnv(['JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=someName']) {
                    sh 'nohup ./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=e1 &'
                }   
}

}
```

For more details and reference, check below the link.
https://www.baeldung.com/jenkins-pipelines

If you do not want to write .jenkins file, you can follow the link and setup manually.
https://medium.com/finoit/continues-integration-using-jenkins-for-java-spring-4439ecd23bec

In case of gradlew clean build, you can provide the the following command.

```
mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=e1
```

Comment: Alternately, set env `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is as below.

Step1: Setup profile in application.properties or application.yml

```
spring.profiles.active=${jenkins.profile}
```

Step2: Setup the environmentin jenkins folder.

Assuming you have folder structure like below.

XXXX_Pipelines --> Stage/MTF/PROD --> app1_pipleline/app2_piplelines

Setup Stage folder properties as jenkins.profile=stage

This will setup the environment variable at runtime.

Comment: The problem is that I want the spring profile to establish the application.properties I will use

Comment: Yes. You need to have all the resource files in your app. application.yml, application-stage.yml etc.. like that... When the above environment variable set it will load both application.yml and application-stage.yml to your app. Does it make sense?

Answer (score -1):

In goals and options under build

```
clean package -Pdev
```

where dev is my profile name